# Use date function to rename a database in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know how to rename a database with the current date

thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL - Rename database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143756/postgresql-rename-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use  dynamic  SQL in a`DO` block. Here I use a date suffix in `YYYYMMDD` format for the database name.

```
knayak=# CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;
CREATE DATABASE
```

---

```
DO $$
BEGIN

 EXECUTE format('ALTER DATABASE %I RENAME TO %I_%s', 'mydatabase','mydatabase',
                               to_char(current_date,'YYYYMMDD')::TEXT);
END
$$;
```

---

```
knayak=#
knayak=# \l mydatabase*
                                    List of databases
        Name         | Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges
---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 mydatabase_20181214 | knayak | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got this Error message:

 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "_20181214"
LINE 1: ALTER DATABASE "mydb" RENAME TO "mydb"_20181214
                                            ^
QUERY:  ALTER DATABASE "mydb" RENAME TO "mydb"_20181214
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 42601

Am I missing something?

Comment: @DanielCampeão : Remove the double quotes, you don't need it

Comment: First I created a database and named it "mydb"

This is how it looks my Query 

[DO $$
BEGIN

 EXECUTE format('ALTER DATABASE %I RENAME TO %I_%s', 'mydb','mydb',
                               to_char(current_date,'YYYYMMDD')::TEXT);
END
$$;] Thanks for your help